# invalid signer or provider (argument="signerOrProvider") from @web3-react/core

Tags: web3js, ether, javascript, ethers.js, uniswap

hello everyone I'm able to connect walletConnect with @web3-react/core but I don't know how to get the provider here's my code.

```
import { InjectedConnector } from "@web3-react/injected-connector"
import { WalletConnectConnector } from "@web3-react/walletconnect-connector"

const injected = new InjectedConnector({
  supportedChainIds: [1, 3, 4, 5, 42],
})

const walletconnect = new WalletConnectConnector({
  rpcUrl: `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_KEY}`,
  bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org",
  qrcode: true,
})

export const connectors = {
  injected: injected,
  walletConnect: walletconnect,
}
```

```
import { Web3ReactProvider } from "@web3-react/core"
import { ethers } from "ethers"

function getLibrary(provider) {
  return new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(provider)
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Web3ReactProvider getLibrary={getLibrary}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Web3ReactProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

```
const contract = {
  address: "0xe138921836cA7A88CBd99Ab280a64f51563691b7",
  abi: [
    {
      inputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "count_", type: "uint256" }],
      name: "add",
      outputs: [],
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function",
    },
    {
      inputs: [],
      name: "count",
      outputs: [{ internalType: "uint256", name: "", type: "uint256" }],
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function",
    },
  ],
}

const {library} = useWeb3React()

const connectWalletOnPageLoad = async () => {
  
    await activate(connectors.walletConnect)
    
    const newContract = new ethers.Contract(
      contract.address,
      contract.abi,
      library?.provider
    )
    const count = await newContract.count()
    console.log(count)
  
}
```

everything works fine except the provider

```
Error: invalid signer or provider (argument="signerOrProvider", value="[object Object]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
```

Comment: Which versions of `@web3-react/core`, `@web3-react/metamask` and `ethers` you have installed?

Comment: you are mixing two different libraries